# How do I move PriorCourtFileNumber element from the bottom to the top of the input document?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I added the following elements

`<PriorCourtFileNumber>
    <CaseNumber>555</CaseNumber>
</PriorCourtFileNumber>`

into a document object **(aobjXMLInputDoc)** but it was added to the bottom of this aobjXMLInputDoc. 
I would like to move it to the top after the element `<Integration>`

How do I do that?

Here is what the aobjXMLInputDoc object look like

```
<Pipeline>
<SourceXML>
    <Integration>
        <Case>
            <CaseNumber/>
        </Case>
        <IntegrationConditions>
            <IntegrationCondition>
                <NotificationEvent/>
            </IntegrationCondition>
        </IntegrationConditions>
        <PriorCourtFileNumber>
            <CaseNumber>555</CaseNumber>
        </PriorCourtFileNumber>
    </Integration>
</SourceXML>
```

Here is what I would like it to look like

```
<Pipeline>
<SourceXML>
    <Integration>
        <PriorCourtFileNumber>
            <CaseNumber>555</CaseNumber>
        </PriorCourtFileNumber>
        <Case>
            <CaseNumber/>
        </Case>
        <IntegrationConditions>
            <IntegrationCondition>
                <NotificationEvent/>
            </IntegrationCondition>
        </IntegrationConditions>
    </Integration>
</SourceXML>
```

Here is my vb.net code that is adding the elements `<PriorCourtFileNumber>` with it's child `<CaseNumber>`

```
objXMLElement = aobjXMLInputDoc.CreateElement("PriorCourtFileNumber")
    aobjXMLInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("SourceXML/Integration").AppendChild(objXMLElement)
    objXMLElement = aobjXMLInputDoc.CreateElement("CaseNumber")
    objXMLElement.InnerText = strPriorCaseNumber
    aobjXMLInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("SourceXML/Integration/PriorCourtFileNumber").AppendChild(objXMLElement)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [InsertBefore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `XmlNode` like this :

```
Dim integrationNode =aobjXMLInputDoc.
     DocumentElement.
     SelectSingleNode("SourceXML/Integration")

integrationNode.InsertBefore(objXMLElement, integrationNode.FirstChild)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems easier than I had though.